# contextLoaderListener configuration, controller not found

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

When I run my sample spring mvc webapplication with just DispatcherServlet it works fine but when I include ContextLoaderlListener also its trying to find controller class from applicationContext.xml which is actually defined in to scan in dispatcher-servlet.xml

Here is my web.xml

```
<context-param>
<param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
<param-value>/WEB-INF/application-context.xml</param-value>
</context-param>


<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>  
</listener>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>myapp</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/myapp-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>


<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>myapp</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Here is my application-context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.startcompany.startapp">
        <context:exclude-filter type="annotation" expression="com.startcompany.startapp.controller"/>
    </context:component-scan>
</beans>
```

And this is myapp-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="com.startcompany.startapp.controller"/>

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/views/jsp/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
```

getting this exception while deploying on tomcat.

```
SEVERE: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Type filter class not found: com.startcompany.startapp.controller; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.startcompany.startapp.controller
Offending resource: ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/application-context.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.startcompany.startapp.controller
at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.FailFastProblemReporter.error(FailFastProblemReporter.java:70)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is related with two contradictory statement in diff file.At one place you are trying to `include` the `controller` package for scanning and at other place you are `excluding` it.

application-context.xml

```
   <context:exclude-filter type="annotation" expression="com.startcompany.startapp.controller"/>
```

**myapp-servlet.xml**

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.startcompany.startapp.controller"/>
```

Comment: Yes I did it intentionally because I want to keep my middle tier and datasource configuration in application context, and myapp-servlet.xml is a dispatcher servlet so i want it to handle only controller. Since in the same root package I will have Service and DAO classes so I excluded controller package from applicatio-context.xml so that controllers are not scanned twice.

Answer (score 0):

In exclude-filter, with type="annotation", you should use an annotation by which the excluded class is marked

```
expression="MyExcludingAnnotation"
```